# Regex Expression For Masking Characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ to mask out portions of strings in a text document.

I have strings similar to this:

> B1541123412341234^TEST
>   DATA^125000000,1541123412341234=00000000000125000000

I need to replace the 12 characters after B1541 with Xs. The result will look like this:

> B1541XXXXXXXXXXXX^TEST
>   DATA^125000000,1541XXXXXXXXXXXX=00000000000125000000

Any advice?

Comment: Is the B going to be in front of the second 1541 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++

Find what : `1541\d{12}`

Replace with : `1541XXXXXXXXXXXX`

output as expected:

```
B1541XXXXXXXXXXXX^TEST DATA^125000000,1541XXXXXXXXXXXX=00000000000125000000
```

Snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Replace `(?<=B1541).{12}` by `XXXXXXXXXXXX` (don't forget to tick the regexp checkbox in Notepad++).

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/DRia46UOaujBIsWO)

Comment: There can by any number of digits.

Comment: @Braj What do you mean?

Comment: There is no need that there is exactly 12 digits after 1541. If it is something like `B15411234^TEST DATA^125,154112341`

Comment: @Braj Then the OP should not have specify *the 12 characters after B1541* ;)

Answer (score 0):

Capture the group of numbers you want:

```
(?<=B1541)(.{12})(.*?)\1(.*)
```

Replace:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX\2XXXXXXXXXXXX\3
```

It finds 12 characters following `B1541`, then "anything", then the same characters again, then "anything else". It replaces both instances of the 12 characters with 12 'X' characters.

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wP2tY5) (with digits only)
[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fK6xQ9) (with any character)